# Is there a getText() equivalent for Scala?/How do I "grab" from a textField in Scala?

Tags: scala

This is how it is used in Java:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
String text = textField.**getText**();
textArea.append(text + newline);
textField.selectAll();
```

}

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you aware you can call Java methods from Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same:

```
val text = textField.getText
```

`JTextField` has a `getText()` method that you can call the same way in scala as you do in Java